# convert script from jQuery 1.9 to 1.8

Tags: jquery-1.9, jquery-1.8

this script works in jQuery 1.9, but does not work in 1.8. How to convert this script to jQuery 1.8 ?

[**NOT Working Demo on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/tzEHe/3/)

[**Working Demo on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/tzEHe/4/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="c1" class="aaa" style="text-align:right; color:red top:100px; ">child 1</div>
    <div id="c2" class="aaa" style="text-align:left; top:200px; ">child 2</div>
</div>
```

jQuery script

```
$("#container").children().each( function () {
    alert("element ID = " + $(this).attr('id'));
    var styleProps = $(this).css(["width", 
                                  "height", 
                                  "color", 
                                  "background-color", 
                                  "text-align", 
                                  "left", 
                                  "top", 
                                  "right", 
                                  "bottom"]);
    $.each(styleProps, function (prop, value) {
        alert(prop + " = " + value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `css` function accepting an array wasn't implemented until [1.9](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyNames).

You'll probably have to do it by hand if you're using 1.8 (loop through the values one at a time).

```
var styleNames = ["width", "height", "color", ...etc... ];

var i;
var $elem = jQuery(this);
for (i = 0; i < styleNames.length; ++i) {
    alert(styleNames[i] + " = " + $elem.css(styleNames[i]));
}
```

Comment: Read my answer again. The css function that accepts an array is not available in jQuery 1.8. The sample I provided works just fine, but you have to actually use it.